# What do I miss in my service's permission

Tags: android, service, android-permissions

I have a **1st application** with a service with only the `onBind()` method which contains a toast.
It's declared like that:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myservice">
    <application
         ...>
        ....
        <service
            android:name=".ServiceApi"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.example.myservice.permission.ACCESS_API"/>
    </application>
```

I have a **2nd application** which tries to bind on the service. 
I declare the access permission in the manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myclient">
    ....
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.myservice.permission.ACCESS_API" />
```

And here is the code:

```
    val componentName = ComponentName("com.example.myservice", "com.example.myservice.ServiceApi")
    val intent = Intent()
    intent.component = componentName
    bindService(intent, mConnection,
            Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
```

And I get the following error:

```
07-14 09:35:13.786 31042-31042/com.example.myclient E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myclient, PID: 31042
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myclient/com.example.myclient.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to bind to service Intent { cmp=com.example.myservice/.ServiceApi }
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to bind to service Intent { cmp=com.example.myservice/.ServiceApi }
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1322)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1286)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:604)
        at com.example.myclient.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.kt:67)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1237)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6268)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

If I remove the `android:permission`in the service application's manifest, I can bind on it successfully as I can see the toast.

I build with `minSdkVersion=19` and `compileSdkVersion=28`
What do I miss?

Comment: can you post the full logcat error

Comment: @masoud-vali. Yep it's done

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to have the permission declaration in the manifest in the 1st application

```
 <permission android:name="com.example.myservice.permission.ACCESS_API" 
       android:protectionLevel="normal"/>
```

Comment: The protection level doesn't change anything

Comment: I'm not talking about the protection level, i'm talking about the declaration of the permission. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/defining#defining

You need to declare the permission and then you can protect the service with that permission

Answer (score 0):

try adding `android:process=":my_process"` to your service tag in first application.
[service elements](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element)

Comment: No, that doesn't change anything. And that tag is for detacthing the service in another process in fact.